# About the proof of the inequality: $\int_0^1 |f(x)|dx\le\text{max}\left(\int_0^1 |f’(x)|dx, \left\vert\int_0^1 f(x)dx\right\vert\right)$

Tags: calculus, integration, inequality, integral-inequality

设f(x)导数处处连续，证明：
∫|f(x)|dx≤MAX{∫|f'(x)|dx,|∫f(x)dx|}.
三个都为定积分 x from 0 to 1.

我用到了MAX{A,B}=(A+B+|A-B|)/2.加上|A-B|≥|A|-|B|.
但是和要证的不等号方向相反。

Translation:

Let $f$ be a function such that $f'$ is continuous everywhere, prove

> $$\int_0^1 |f(x)|dx\le\text{max}\left(\int_0^1 |f’(x)|dx, \left\vert\int_0^1 f(x)dx\right\vert\right)$$

I have used $\text{max}(A,B)=\frac{A+B+|A-B|}2$ and $|A-B|\ge|A|-|B|$, however what I need to prove has the reversed inequality sign.

Comment: I am Chinese and I understand them but, please, use English. Also, please add context and show your effort.

Comment: Please ask your question in English; by posting it in Chinese, you've tripped the community's spam filter, hence the downvotes. We're working on retracting them.

Comment: @Szeto Then you could have translated it by editing. Among the guidelines of the site, there is in fact one that suggests that weak English speakers might rather post in their mothertongue and let others translate, if they realize that they're uncapable of writing a proper English text.

Comment: Sorry, for a moment, please forgive my rudeness

Comment: @SaucyO'Path Just done.

Comment: Is this questions along the lines of what you wanted to ask: [An inequality of $\int_0^1 |f(x)|dx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/59851). I have searched [using Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Cint_0%5E1%20%7Cf(x)%7Cdx%5Cle%5Cint_0%5E1%20%7Cf’(x)%7Cdx%24&p=1) - maybe you can find some other similar posts.

Comment: You should have $|A-B|\geq |A|-|B|$.

Comment: @LorenzoQuarisa That’s my typo. Do not blame the OP.

Comment: I didn't blame anyone. Anyway, with this adjustment, it seems like the inequality sign is not reversed.

Comment: Delighted to see the post has no more downvotes:)

Comment: By the way, $f'$ does not make sense for an arbitrary continuous function, you need additional assumptions.

Comment: @LorenzoQuarisa Indeed, the OP stated the derivative is continuous everywhere. Again, I translated it wrongly.

Answer (score 2):

If $f>0$ or $f<0$ everywhere then the inequality is obviuous. Otherwise $f(c)=0$ for some $c$. Let $g =\frac f {R.H.S}$. Note that $\int |g'(t)|\, dt  \leq 1$ and $|\int g(t)\, dt | \leq 1$. Now $|g(x)-g(c)|=|\int_c^{x} g'(t)\, dt| \leq \int_{0}^{1} |g'(t)|\, dt \leq1$ so $|g(x)| \leq 1$ for all $x$ and $\int_0^{1} |g(x)|\, dx \leq 1$.  If you write $g$ in terms of $f$ you get the desired inequality.